# Qt: prepend text to file

Tags: c++, qt, file

I wanted to write to a file and I did it, but it always writes to the last line. Is there a way to make it write to the first line?  For example, given a file containing

```
apple
orange
```

and I want to add "banana"; I want the file to become:

```
banana  
apple
orange
```

My current code is:

```
void Write (QString file)
{
    QFile sfile(file);
    if(!sfile.open(QFile::Append |QFile::Text))
    {
        return;
    }
    QTextStream out(&sfile);
    out <<"        "<<xscore<<"        "<<oscore<<endl;
    sfile.close();
}
```

How should I change this to insert text at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append`ing to a file will allways add `at the end`.

if you want to insert the first line, you can read the current file content (`buffer`), open it for writing and write your `new content` followed by the `buffer`

/edit:

a small example could look like this...

```
QFile sfile(file);
sfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
QByteArray buffer = sfile.readAll();
sfile.close();
sfile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text);
QTextStream out(&sfile);
out <<"        "<<xscore<<"        "<<oscore<<endl;
out << buffer;
```